# Unable to run R shiny containing a locally installed package

Tags: r, shiny

I want to deploy an application on R shiny on the web, but I get this error

> Preparing to deploy application...DONE
>   Uploading bundle for application: 63131...Error: 
>   * Unable to deploy package dependency 'CellMix'
>
> The package was installed locally from source. Only packages
>   installed from CRAN, BioConductor and GitHub are supported. Execution
>   halted

Is there a work around to run the application and deploy on the web.

Comment: No workaround. Either you install shiny-server locally or you integrate the local package code to the shiny application (you remove the local package dependency).

Comment: Thank you for the response. guess will try installing shiny-server locally